# Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Category::$thesizes has no effect

Tags: php, laravel

For a webshop im trying to generate a table that looks like:

```
Tablename: category 1
productname     S   M   L   X  total
name1           1    0  1   3  5
name2           0    1  0   2  3


Tablename: category 2
productname     S   L   X  total
name5           1   1   3  5
name8           0   0   2  2
```

There is  a table for each category, each category has his own sizes (table 2 has no size M for example). 
The tables show the amount of ordered products per size per product in each category.

In the application there is a model **OrderProducts** which are ordered products in each **Order**.

An **OrderProduct** has a **ProductSize** which is a  junction table of the product sizes

A **ProductSize** has a **Size** (which contains the name of the size)

The first step im tryin to do is get all sizes/products for each category like:

```
    $order = Order::findOrFail($id);
    $products = OrderProduct::where('orders_id',$id)->get();

    $categories = Category::all();
    //get sizes and products per category
    foreach($categories as $cat)
    {
        $cat->thesizes= array();
        $cat->theprodcts= array();
        foreach($products as $product)
        {
            if($product->productSize->product->category_id == $cat->id)
            {
                array_push($cat->thesizes,$product->productSize);
                array_push($cat->theprodcts,$product);
            }

        }
        //make sure all values are unique (no dubbele sizes).
        $cat->theSizes = array_unique($cat->theSizes);
        $cat->theProducts = array_unique($cat->theProducts);
    }
```

When I run my code I get the following error:

> Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Category::$thesizes
>   has no effect

Why do I get this error and how should I solve it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because your `Category` class has the `__get()` and `__set()` [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) implemented.

So line 7 (`$cat->thesizes= array();`) invokes `Category::__set()` and line 12 (`array_push($cat->thesizes,$product->productSize);`) invokes `Category::__get()` *but not* `Category::__set()`. So while you impelemented this with the intention of pushing values onto an array that you set on the Category, it won't work since `array_push()` is working on a return value and not the actual array stored in the Category.

There are a few ways to fix this. The most shortcut way is to change `Category::__get()` to return values by reference, which is done by using a sort-of type-hint on the function's return declaration

```
class Category
{
    public function &__get($key) {
        // body of function
    }
}
```

But this is probably not recommended for reasons I can go into if you're curious.

The more sensible approach, without significantly modifying your code at least, is to build the arrays within the scope of the loop and *then* add them to your `Category` objects

```
foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    // Scope local arrays here first
    $thesizes = array();
    $theproducts = array();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        if ($product->productSize->product->category_id == $cat->id) {
            // Push to those local arrays
            array_push($thesizes, $product->productSize);
            array_push($theprodcts, $product);
        }
    }

    // Now assign them to the category object
    $cat->theSizes = array_unique($thesizes);
    $cat->theProducts = array_unique($theproducts);
}
```

If you want to go for bonus points, since this is Laravel and your return values are [collections](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Collection.php), you can do something like this for a more sophisticated implementation

```
$categories = (Category::all())->map(function(Category $cat) {
    $cat->theProducts = $products
        ->filter(function(Product $product) use ($cat) {
            return $product->productSize->product->category_id == $cat->id;
        })
        ->unique();

    $cat->theSizes = $cat->theProducts
        ->map(function(Product $product) {
            return $product->productSize();
        })->unique();
});
```

Comment: Hey, I realize you already accepted this but I noted the [laravel] tag so I updated my collections example based on that.

Comment: I also came up with the more sensible way you posted, thanks for the explenation I did not know about the magic methods, I guess i'll have to do some studying on them soon as I do not understand how/when they are used at the moment. As for the collections example I think the sensible example is more readable. Thanks for your well explained help.

Answer (score 1):

Following trick has worked for me

```
public function methods(){
     //other logics
     ...
    $result = json_decode(json_encode($result));

    $result->someProp = (object)[];
    $result->someProp->another = 'test';

    return response()->json($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the error happens is that when you are array_push to an Object of the Category Object although the Field might be an array, however it lives in an object you must save the field to an array variable then array_push to that variable and then back to the field as a json string

Answer (score 0):

Try to use custom casting as below

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Foo extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'bar' => 'collection',
    ];
}
```

Then you can update or add item as below:

```php
$foo = Foo::find(1);

$foo->bar['a'] = 'b';
$foo->save();
```