# Laravel Pluck 3 arrays

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

can I pluck the 3 arrays like these because only two are shown?

```
$data = Receipt::select(DB::raw("DATE(created_on) as date"), DB::raw("sum(case when type = 'Receipt' then 1 else 0 end) AS cnt_receipt"), DB::raw("sum(case when type = 'Invoice' then 1 else 0 end) AS cnt_invoice"))
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->pluck('cnt_receipt', 'cnt_invoice', 'date')->all();
```

If not, how can I able show those 3 arrays?

I want the output something like this

```
date                 cnt_receipt       cnt_invoice
2021-01-01             5                6
2021-01-02             8                5
2021-01-03            10                9
2021-01-04            11                9
```

I need to get those data as arrays because the chart js code need array_keys and array_values

```
$chart= new Chart;
$chart->labels = (array_keys($data));
$chart->r_dataset = (array_values($data));
$chart->i_dataset = (array_values($data));
```

Chart Class

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Chart extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Comment: you want to get these 3 values 'cnt_receipt', 'cnt_invoice', 'date' ?

Comment: delete this line and try again ->all()

Comment: I try delete that line ```->all()``` and it has error ```array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given```

Comment: use ->toArray()

Comment: It also returns the same results as all(). I'll edit my question to show what should be the output.

Comment: i dont know what you are doing in your query but in laravel with: ->value('column1','column2') or ->pluck('column1','column2') or even ->get('column1','column2') you can get columns you want

Comment: For this purpose, I need to get three arrays for my chart because it would require array keys.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is `reduce` here, a bit of a hacky way, but it will work.

```
$data = Receipt::select(DB::raw("DATE(created_on) as date, sum(case when type = 'Receipt' then 1 else 0 end) AS cnt_receipt, sum(case when type = 'Invoice' then 1 else 0 end) AS cnt_invoice"))
   ->groupBy('date')->all();
```

Then;

```php
$chartInitial = new Chart();
$chartInitial->labels = [];
$chartInitial->r_dataset = [];
$chartInitial->i_dataset = [];

$chart = $data->reduce(function($obj, $row){
    $obj->labels[] = $row->date;
    $obj->r_dataset[] = $row->cnt_receipt;
    $obj->i_dataset[] = $row->cnt_invoice;
    return $obj;
}, $chartInitial);
```

It'll push all the row data into their respective arrays in that Chart object.

Comment: ```Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Chart::$labels has no effect``` at the code ```$obj->labels[]```

Comment: Can you share the code of your `App\Charts` model?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462131/indirect-modification-of-overloaded-property-app-categorythesizes-has-no-effe

Comment: I do not put any code in ```App\Chart``` model

Comment: Can you share the `Chart` class?